# Objective-c storyboard - Navigation Bar in UITableViewController not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I created a `UITableViewController` scene in my storyboard.

Now I am trying to add a Navigation Bar to my `UITableViewController` by simply dragging the Navigation Bar to it, but when I run my app I do not see the Navigation Bar. Here is a screenshot of my Navigation Bar inside my `UITableViewController` in my storyboard. What am I doing wrong?

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I guess you have to embed your tableview controller in a navigation controller (Mark tableview controller, Editor->Embed In) and oc remove the navigation bar from the tableview's content view.

Comment: nope that did not work

Comment: Just select your tableviewcontroller, Go to Editor(in top bar of xcode)->Embed in ->Navigation Controller. check if navigation is not hidden in File Inspector. As everyone suggested, remove navigation bar from content view.

Comment: `check if navigation is not hidden in File Inspector.` I don't understand this part.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have navigation bar inside table view. The navigation bar is placed at the top consuming 64 pixels, out of which around 24 belongs to status bar. So instead of going through all this mess, Select the View controller and select Editor[image]

After that select navigation controller and set its property to "Is initial view controller."

Comment: That didn't work either...this is extremely frustrating

Answer (score 0):

In your case you put navigation bar in the tableView cell. If you use dynamic tableView you first have to implement UITableView's dataSource and Delegate methods. Only then you will see the cell's content.

But it seems that you have put it inside a cell by mistake. Drag the navigation bar a little but above the cell, but not in the cell exactly.

Comment: it won't let me drag the navigation bar above the cell :(

Answer (score 0):

You have used navigationBar inside the UITableView Cell , if you want to use navigationBar use **UINavigationController** from story borad that is the best option and assign your tableViewController to its rootViewController.